# Unable to set cookie: Cef.SetCookie() always returns false

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

This issue has been puzzling me for a couple of days now. I'm completely unable to set a cookie using `CefSharp`.

Here's the code block that I'm expecting to work (more so because it's as naive as can be, excluding the explicit thread context switch):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    var settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.CachePath = "cookies";

    Cef.Initialize(settings);

    Cef.DeleteCookies("", ""); 
    Cef.VisitAllCookies(new CookieVisitor());  // <-- doesn't get called, so assuming we've cleared all the persistent cookies here...

    Cef.SetCookiePath("/", false);
    Cef.VisitAllCookies(new CookieVisitor());  // <-- ok guess im paranoid...
    var isSet = Cef.SetCookie("/", "username", 
                    "testuser", "tovalrsv01", "/", 
                    false, false, false, new DateTime(2020, 1, 1));

    Cef.VisitAllCookies(new CookieVisitor()); // <-- isSet is false, and i don't see the cookie that i created in the visited list...
}));
```

I'm just wondering if I'm missing some important concept here. I'm new to `CefSharp` and despite having pored over the examples and the forums, it's highly possible that I've missed something here. Would greatly appreciate any insights or pointers!

Answer (score 5):

Argggh!  I figured it out after more trial and errors. A post on this site helped me on my investigation:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cefsharp/SflbtatvTqQ

> Try passing in an empty string for domain rather than "/" or pass in Url as "/mywebsite" and domain as "192.16.1.6"

This made me wonder if my cookie params were being rejected for one reason or another. I ended up trying to set the cookie with these params:

`var isSet = Cef.SetCookie("http://tovalrsv01:8142/", "username", "testuser", "", "/", false, false, false, new DateTime(2020, 1, 1));`

Specifying the URL a bit more rigorously was what did the trick. I guess DNS aliases are not good enough, sometimes. Anyways, I'm going to leave this post in case other `CefSharp`ers run into a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I have used below code to add cookie.

```
var mngr = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
Cookie Ac = new Cookie();
Ac.Name = "<Cookie Name>";
Ac.Value = "<Value>";
mngr.SetCookieAsync(<URL to Navigate>, Ac);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestion of Akash Patel. But that example doesnt work in my case(CefSharp.OffScreen 71.0.2), so I have edited it like this:

```
//_browser is object of ChromiumWebBrowser
var cookieManager=_browser.RequestContext.GetDefaultCookieManager(null);
Cookie cookie = new Cookie
{
    Name = name,
    Value = value
};
cookieManager.SetCookie(url, cookie);
//or cookieManager.SetCookieAsync(url, cookie);
```